# Check SMTP server working or not with powershell {send-mailmessage}

Tags: shell, email, powershell, smtp, monitoring

How to check if SMTP server is working or not. Basically I have:

```
SMTPserver= mail.my1stdomain.com, 
FromAddress=mymailbox@my1stdomain.com, 
ToAddress=Recipient@my1stdomain.com.
```

I want to check if I can send email.  If I can it is ok, but if the Powershell script output is an error, then I want to use my second SMTP server to notify that the first SMTP server failed to send email.

My second set of SMTP info is:

```
SMTPserver=mail.my2nddomain.com, 
FromAddress=mymailbox@my2nddomain.com, 
ToAddress=Recipient@my2nddomain.com
```

I've used this script to send email:

```
Send-MailMessage -from mymailbox@my1stdomain.com -to Recipient@my1stdomain.com -Subject "Test OK" -Body "Test is OK" -SmtpServer mail.my1stdomain.com
```

Of course to send email via second SMTP server I have to do this:

```
Send-MailMessage -from mymailbox@my2nddomain.com -to Recipient@my2nddomain.com -Subject "Test OK" -Body "Test is OK" -SmtpServer mail.my2nddomain.com
```

I don't know how to write IF case in case of 1st command fails

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do a simple try catch:

```
try{
    Send-MailMessage -from mymailbox@my1stdomain.com -to Recipient@my1stdomain.com -Subject "Test OK" -Body "Test is OK" -SmtpServer mail.my1stdomain.com
   }
catch{
    Send-MailMessage -from mymailbox@my2nddomain.com -to Recipient@my2nddomain.com -Subject "Test OK" -Body "Test is OK" -SmtpServer mail.my2nddomain.com
   }
```

If the code block in try generates error it will run the catch block.

Comment: I've tried this one, and it's working well. Thnx 
try {
    Send-MailMessage -from mymailbox@my1stdomain.com -to Recipient@my1stdomain.com -Subject "Test SMTP OK" -Body "Test SMTP OK" -SmtpServer mail.my1stdomain.com -ErrorAction Stop
    Write-Debug $DebugPreference Continue
} catch {
    $ErrorMessage = $_.Exception.Message
    $FailedItem = $_.Exception.ItemName
    Send-MailMessage -from mymailbox@my2nddomain.com -to Recipient@my2nddomain.com -Subject "Test SMTP FAILED" -Body "$FailedItem , $ErrorMessage" -SmtpServer mail.my2nddomain.com
    }

Comment: Good to hear, you can now accept the answer so we can help others.